# Is what I am asking considered dependency injection for WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working with a fellow employee on a web service layer to our product. He has put together some service methods, but they all require the same object. Here is an example:

```
public interface IQueueService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        UserBase LoginUser(MessageBase message, string userName, string password);

        [OperationContract]
        bool LogoutUser(MessageBase message, string userName);
}
```

As you can see every methods requires the MethodBase object. What is the best method to require that object using a “kind / sorta WCF constructor” before any other methods can be called. Is this what dependency injection is? I have been reading about that, but not sure it is what we need.

I suppose we could have a method to create the MethodBase instance and if it doesn’t exist in any other method, we throw an exception?

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: totally unrelated but what kind of naming convention are you following there? It looks like Hungarian which should be extinguished by now, and for good reasons.

Comment: please don't go there ;) I have been fighting this battle for over 6 months now. I 1000% agree, and actaully thought about changing the example ;)

Comment: i changed it becuase it was hurting my eyes too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF is interface based - and you don't have constructors for interfaces, so dependency injection isn't going to help you.

Depending on what kind of interaction you're expecting clients to have with the service, and depending on the semantics of your `MessageBase` class, you may want to go with a connection oriented design:

```
public interface IQueueService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true)]
    void Connect(MessageBase message);

    [OperationContract]
    UserBase LoginUser(string userName, string password);

    [OperationContract]
    bool LogoutUser(string userName);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    void Disconnect();
}
```

Your clients need to first `Connect()`, supplying a `MessageBase`, then call an operation (say, `LoginUser()`) then call `Disconnect()`.

Of course, this is all dependent on semantics that you haven't supplied.

Comment: This lead me to think of sessions for WCF. Thanks!